# Why am I getting "no space left on device" when it appears that there's lots of space free?

Tags: fedora-23

I am trying to install RASA Core but when running the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 501, in unzip_file
    fp.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Funny thing is that my VM has space.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 485M     0  485M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    497M  4.0K  497M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    497M  660K  496M   1% /run
tmpfs                    497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   39G  8.2G   31G  22% /
tmpfs                    497M   45M  452M   9% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M  125M  323M  28% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   19G 1006M   18G   6% /home
tmpfs                    100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. 
One last thing..I am trying to install in directory:

```
/vas/projects/rasa/rasa_core
```

and with the following command

```
df -h /vas/projects/rasa/rasa_core/
```

I get:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   39G  8.2G   31G  22% /
```

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Check your inodes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage

Comment: I used command df -ih and got
IUse% all 1%

Comment: What happens if you try to install it somewhere under /home, just to check?

Comment: same thing happens: IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that you have a rather small `/tmp` filesystem:

```
tmpfs                    497M   45M  452M   9% /tmp
```

You are getting the error while pip is trying to unpack a file. My guess is that it is trying to unpack that file to a temporary location, and then intends to move it it place — and that it's bigger than ~450MB.

By default, `/tmp` is an in-memory filesystem configured with a limit of half of your RAM. Assuming this is the problem, you have three options:

1. If you have sufficient swap configured, increase the limit from the default. (tmpfs is swappable, so the excess will use your swap file.) Instructions on that [from this [unix-SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352042/2511)).
2. Disable the `/tmp` mount, so that `/tmp` is just a directory on the `/` filesystem where you have plenty of space. Do this with `systemctl mask tmp.mount`.
3. Set the `TMPDIR` directory to `/var/tmp` instead of `/tmp`.